# How to configure Kibana 4 to query multiple Elasticsearch clusters?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I want to create Kibana 4 dashboard with multiple indices in different ES clusters.

Elastic - 2 cluster (with 14 data nodes, 1 tribe node each)

[image: Pictorial representation of this question]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: I'm also curious about this. I'm hoping to build a dashboard that brings together data from both our production cluster and dev cluster.